# I have tried many methods and I couldn't find solution. So how to convert Python file to executables?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, executable, cx-freeze

- Python : 3.5
- PYinstaller : 3.5
- Win64
- cx_Freeze : 6.0

According to the above information, I have tried to convert Python project to exe but it does not work.

First I have tried pyinstaller but the process throw some error:

[image: when trying pyinstaller]

After that, I have tried cx_Freeze and it works, but the exe are working on some computer but not on every computer that have same platform.

[image: when trying cx_Freeze]

I don't know what I can do. I looked for google and stackoverflow but there are unsolved problems or I couldn't see the solution.

Later I have tried to change python version but doesn't work again. Computers that have tried to running the exe, have same OS platform, I'm sure.

By the way,  [if you receive the following cx_Freeze error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1iP8.png), resolving like this:

```
Build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\lib\scipy\spatial\cKDTree.cp37-win_amd64
```

change to

```
Build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\lib\scipy\spatial\ckdtree.cp37-win_amd64
```

Program uses the following modules : tkinter, pydicom, skimage, PIL, cv2, etc.

Primarily Program has 2 page that content code but I made single file for I came across this sentence "It's worth noting that pyinstaller can compile to a single .exe file"

What do you suggest I do? Thanks for your help.

Edit: I have been tried "Auto-py-to-exe" but I got an error (Fatal Error : Failed to execute script")

Edit2: I tried to run outside the anaconda. I think its work. But I'm still testing.

Edit3: I have tried to change python version, GUI was opened another computer but the program is not work  properly. the program works on my computer but not on another computers

Comment: I've had good experience with pyinstaller, not under windows though - what you created is a "one directory" (good for debugging). It also has a "one file" setting. 

Essentially it creates a self-contained python environment with everything that's required by the script. The one-file executable is an archive which self-extracts into a temporary dir. Possibly it's worth to look into this further.

Comment: if you talk about "auto-py-to-exe (pyinstaller)", I have already tried this method

Comment: Were you able to export and run a simple "hello-world" style script? Also, I would use the underlying pyinstaller package directly (as [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)), rather than a gui wrapper as you seem to be doing - at least for debugging

Comment: yes, I have tried to run "helloworld" its run. But dont convert to exe python project to exe. i have tried to convert exe as code but its not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to convert python file to executable format, you can try using auto py-to-exe library.

This library contains a GUI format to convert .py files to .exe

Here you can find auto py-to-exe with usage instructions,

https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Comment: I have tried auto-py-to-exe but I  got an error "Fatal Error: Failed to execute script"